# Change primary and foreign key in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models :

```
class Settlement < ActiveRecord::Base
 set_primary_key :settlement_identifier
 has_many :streets
 attr_accessible :city, :name, :service_available, :zip, :country_id,:  settlement_identifier

end

class Street < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :settlement, foreign_key: "settlement_identifier"
 attr_accessible :name, :settlement_identifier, :street_identifier
end
```

Because I am doing import for streets and settlements, I need to point streets via settlement_identifier, not settlement_id . 
When I do

```
Street.first.settlement #it compare settlement_identifiers from both tables
```

But when try to get streets from single settlement like :

```
Settlement.first.streets
```

It throws an error

```
SELECT "streets".* FROM "streets" WHERE "streets"."settlement_id" = 4263

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column streets.settlement_id does not exist .
```

I want that query to be :

```
SELECT "streets".* FROM "streets" WHERE "streets"."settlement_identifier" = 4263
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. Here is solution below :

```
 class CreateSettlements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :settlements, primary_key: :settlement_identifier, id: :false do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.string :zip
    t.string :city
    t.string :service_available
    t.integer :country_id

    t.timestamps
   end
  end
 def down
  drop_table :settlements
 end
end
```

Here I set primary_key in my migration to settlement_identifier, and set id to false

Also, my Street migration is:

```
class CreateStreets < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :streets do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.integer :settlement_identifier
   t.string :street_identifier
   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

So, Street has reference to Settlement via settlement_identifier .

Settlement model :

```
class Settlement < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :streets, foreign_key: "settlement_identifier"

 attr_accessible :city, :name, :service_available,:settlement_identifier
end
```

Street model :

```
 class Street < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :settlement, foreign_key: "settlement_identifier"

  attr_accessible :name, :settlement_identifier, :street_identifier

 end
```

I tried to set primary_key on Settlement model but that didn't work. 
This works fine for me. If anyone have another solution, please put comment or code example.